# I want to draw a focus indicator on camera view

Tags: objective-c, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

I made an application using the camera.
I didn't use the default camera toolbar. 
So I add a toolbar on camera overlay view.

I want to draw tap to focus indicator
So I used UITapGestureRecognizer.
Here is the code

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *focusRect = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(drawFocusRect:)];
focusRect.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
focusRect.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[cameraPicker.view addGestureRecognizer:focusRect];
[focusRect release];
```

In the drawFocusRect method

```
NSLog(@"tapped");
```

But it dosen't work. 
I changed the value of numberOfTouchedRequired, 2;
And it works.
I think that it doen't work when only single-tap
So, how can I implement this single tapping gesture processing method?

Answer (score 0):

I think camera view's focus view at top of all view.
And I think it has single tap action.
So If you want do this, you should read AVCamera demo in WWDC2010.